# print() occasionally failing to show in command prompt

Tags: python, terminal, command-prompt

I have a python script that scrapes a page, outputs some data, and then sleeps for 5 minutes before repeating the process.

I have noticed that about 1/5 times I run this script, after a seemingly random period of time the prints will stop showing up in the command prompt, but as soon as I type any key in the terminal they suddenly appear.

```
while True:
   # request & parse page
   # print results
   # sleep for 5 minutes
```

There are never any errors and the script keeps running along fine, but I'm confused why the prints stop appearing temporarily.

Is there a way to ensure this does not happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try `print("blash", flush=True)`.

Not surprisingly, [the documentation for print()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#print) isn't exactly clear.  The data being printed is likely stored in a buffer at some point and it maybe that the buffer is overwriting itself or not able to keep pace with the data being processed.  The `flush` parameter clears the buffer.

The documentation states,

> Whether output is buffered is usually determined by *file*, but if the
>   *flush* keyword argument is true, the stream is forcibly flushed.

I haven't profiled it, but my guess is that flushing on every print will *technically* slow things down.  But try it out and see how it works for you before trying to optimize.

Comment: First of all, I do find it surprising that the documentation isn't clear, because it usually is. Secondly, the vagueness you seem to be noting is likely because the `print()` function supports the output to be directed to different streams, the default being `sys.stdout` (which varies depending on the OS and how the interpreter was invoked), plus a given stream may or may not be buffered — so it _can't_ be completely definitive.